InvocationTargetException when using PowerMockito to test Static Methods
I have a final class ConfigurationManager that has a method getProps(CONF). I have to mock and return "true" when this method is called.
    public final class       ConfigurationManager {

        public static String     getProps(String prop){
        return AnotherClass.function(prop) }
        }

So I have used PowerMockito to mock this.
In test file, I didnt use     @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and PrepareForTest(ConfiguarationManager.class)
i just called
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConfigurationManager.class);
            Mockito.when(ConfigurationManager.getProps("prop")).thenReturn("true");

But it says "cannot subclass final class ConfigurationManager"
So I used
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
        @PrepareForTest({ConfigurationManager.class)
        public class MangementTest{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    }

But now its error is "org.objenesis.ObjenesisException : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"
I have to mock final class
ConfigurationManager's static method "getProps(string)" to return "true" when called.
